# Check if a value exists using multiple conditions within group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Following is what my dataframe looks like. `Expected_Output` is my desired/target column.

```
   Group  Value1  Value2  Expected_Output
0      1       3       9             True
1      1       7       6             True
2      1       9       7             True
3      2       3       8            False
4      2       8       5            False
5      2       7       6            False
```

If **any** `Value1 == 7` **AND** if **any** `Value2 == 9` within a given `Group`, then I want to return `True`.

I tried to no avail:

```
df['Expected_Output']= df.groupby('Group').Value1.isin(7) &  df.groupby('Group').Value2.isin(9)
```

N.B:- Either True/False or 1/0 can be output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `groupby` on `Group` column and then use `transform` and `lambda function` as:

```
g = df.groupby('Group')
df['Expected'] = (g['Value1'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(7).any()))&(g['Value2'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(9).any()))
```

Or using `groupby`, `apply` and `merge` using parameter `how='left'` as:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x['Value1'].eq(7).any()&x['Value2'].eq(9).any()).reset_index(),how='left').rename(columns={0:'Expected_Output'})
```

Or using `groupby`, `apply` and `map` as:

```
df['Expected_Output'] = df['Group'].map(df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x['Value1'].eq(7).any()&x['Value2'].eq(9).any()))
```

---

```
print(df)
   Group  Value1  Value2  Expected_Output
0      1       3       9             True
1      1       7       6             True
2      1       9       7             True
3      2       3       8            False
4      2       8       5            False
5      2       7       6            False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a dataframe of the expected result by group and then merge it back to the original dataframe.

```
expected = (
    df.groupby('Group')
    .apply(lambda x: (x['Value1'].eq(7).any() 
                      & x['Value2'].eq(9)).any())
    .to_frame('Expected_Output'))
>>> expected
       Expected_Output
Group                 
1                 True
2                False

>>> df.merge(expected, left_on='Group', right_index=True)
   Group  Value1  Value2  Expected_Output
0      1       3       9             True
1      1       7       6             True
2      1       9       7             True
3      2       3       8            False
4      2       8       5            False
5      2       7       6            False
```